# Peculiar error for transition coverage

Tags: transition, specman, function-coverage

[image: screenshot of the error message]

Hi all,
         I am facing a strange error message while debugging a code for functional coverage specifically transition coverage.There are two level pins for fifo1 and fifo2 respectively while doing coverage for the first level pin ie level1 the code is parsed successfully but for level2 pin its throwing an error which says:

```
***Error:Syntax error(probably an infinite recursion in macro expansion)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before loading your code, do `trace macro`.  This will show which macros are being expanded.  Look in your docs for more details.

Also, unless you're just writing some simple prototyping code, `'tick notation'` for accessing signals is *VERY* slow.  It's the old method.  Cadence's recommendation is to use ports instead of `'tick access'`.  We sped up our test runs by a factor of ~3-10x ( can't remember precisely) by using ports instead of ticks when we did the switch back in version 6.01 of Specman.